ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) or not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
I am trying to train T5 model binary classification. When I am trying to
define data class, I am getting
batch_size, seq_length = input_shape
1017 # required mask seq length can be calculated via length of past
1018 mask_seq_length = past_key_values[0][0].shape[2] + seq_length if past_key_values is not None else seq_length

If I am using unsqueeze(0)  for input_id and attention_mask I am getting following error
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

if I am using squeeze(0), flatten() or none of them I am getting
not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

The data class is below
......
  def __init__(self,
               df: pd.DataFrame,
               tokenizer:T5Tokenizer,
               source_max_token_length: int=1000,
               target_max_token_length: int=400):
    self.tokenizer=tokenizer
    self.df=df
    self.source_max_token_length=source_max_token_length
    self.target_max_token_length=target_max_token_length

  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.df)
  def __getitem__(self,index: int):
    data_row=self.df.iloc[index]
    source_encoding=tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(
      str(data_row['question']),
      # str(data_row['context']),
      max_length=self.source_max_token_length,
      padding='max_length',
      truncation='only_second',
      return_attention_mask=True,
      add_special_tokens=True,
      return_tensors='pt'
    )
    target_encoding=tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(
      str(data_row['answers']),
      max_length=self.target_max_token_length,
      padding='max_length',
      truncation=True,
      return_attention_mask=True,
      add_special_tokens=True,
      return_tensors='pt'
    )

    labels=target_encoding['input_ids']
    labels[labels==0]=-100
    return dict(
        question=data_row['question'],
        # context=data_row['context'],
        answer_text=data_row['answers'],
        # input_ids=np.array([source_encoding['input_ids']]),#.flatten(),np.array([d['input_ids']])
        # attention_mask=np.array([source_encoding['attention_mask']]),#.flatten(),#.flatten(),
        # labels=labels
        input_ids=source_encoding['input_ids'].unsqueeze(0),#.flatten(),#.flatten(),np.array([d['input_ids']])
        attention_mask=source_encoding['attention_mask'].unsqueeze(0),#.flatten(),#.flatten(),#.flatten(),
        labels=labels.flatten()
    )

I tried ever debugging like:
example=tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(
      str(data_row['question']),
      # str(data_row['context']),
      max_length=1000,
      padding='max_length',
      truncation='only_second',
      return_attention_mask=True,
      add_special_tokens=True,return_tensors='pt'
      )

The size of example is example['input_ids'].shape
example['input_ids'].shape
torch.Size([61, 1000])

I think I do not need unsqueeze(0) or flatten(), but none of them works
sagemaker: 2.221.0
transformers: 4.41.0
pytorch_lightning: 1.1.3

I don't understand how you are getting both of those errors.  Please update the question and add the full error traceback message, so we don't have to guess what the real error is and where it happened.

A previously indicated by user JohnGordon, please share the full stack trace for your error. You only shared the final error message - a full stack trace will help us see where the problem arises and in what context it happens.
